# ProGuard : how to keep a whole class but its contructor

Tags: proguard

Is there any way to specify to keep all members & methods of a class BUT not its constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-keep` option and specify the constructor name. More information is here (scroll down to the "Keep Options" section: [Proguard Usage](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html)

For example, you can do something like this using the !:

```
-keep class !com.yourcompany.YourClass {
  <init>(...);
}
```

Comment: I know how to keep using wildcard fields, methods, etc... but I want to keep "everything" BUT constructors without having to specify manually each field, each method, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's an unusual requirement, but this should work:

```
-keepclassmembers class mypackage.MyClass {
  <fields>;
  *** !<init>(...);
}
```

The third line matches methods with any return value, any arguments, and any name, except `<init>`.

Keeping a class with `-keep` also automatically preserves its parameterless constructor.

Instantiating a class in the code of course also results in the corresponding constructor being kept.

Comment: Reckon weird requirement ;-) trying to remove several warnings. The 3rd line seems to remove the methods as well.